# Error in RegEx, Find words

Tags: java, regex

I want to find words, semi punctuation, end punctuation and code tag using regex.
I wrote down this pattern:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<digitAndWord>[\\w]+)|(?<semi>[,;:\\-\"\'])|(?<end>[!\\?\\.]+) | (?<code><code>(?<content>.+?)</code>)");
```

But, when there is end punctuation before code tag, matcher ignore it:

```
String input = "are you! <code>String I want to extract</code> ok?";
```

This String works ok, but matcher ignore end punctuation if it is last symbol:

```
String input = "are you, <code>String I want to extract</code> ok?";
```

Please, help me to fix error.

Comment: Maybe a typo? But remove the space between your separators `|`, See [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/dM9tU2)

Comment: as @hwnd said, try it [without the spaces](http://regex101.com/r/dC4hG2) before and after the `|` character `(?<digitAndWord>[\\w]+)|(?<semi>[,;:\\\-\"\'])|(?<end>[!\\?\\.]+)|(?<code><code>(?<content>.+?)<\/code>)`

Comment: Please answer your own question and accept it if the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all! Remove spaces helped to solve problem!